# Как остановить @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])?

Tags: python, telebot, циклы

Пишу код для Телеграм бота, бот обладает командой /support, которая включает в себя @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']). Когда пользователь отправляет какое-то сообщение, то оно отправляется админу, а команда **должна** остановится, то есть @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) более **не должен** работать, но этого не происходит, так как это цикл, есть ли способ как его остановить?

Если может понадобиться, вот код часть кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['support'])
def support1(message):
    usr_prb = message.chat.id
    Nusr_prb = message.from_user.username
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Опишите вашу проблему для рассмотрения администрацией проекта.')
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def support2(message):
        problem = message.text
        bot.send_message(admin_id, f' Поступила новая жалоба от участника команды\nПользователь: {usr_prb}, @{Nusr_prb} \n\n{problem}')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваша жалоба будет учтена.')
        # Тут выключатель для @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
```

Comment: по вашей логике у пользователя может быть только одна "проблема", о которой он может написать вашему боту?

Comment: @ZxNuClear, я уже решил проблему поставив локальные флаги по пути кода